# Difficulty in producing map in R

Tags: r, csv

## 1. The Problem

I hope everyone is well at this time.

I am in the middle of an important assignment for university. I need to produce a map with the sites that were sampled during data collection. I have attached the code I have produced thus far. I am, however, struggling to complete the code.

If anyone could offer some suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks,

Boru

## 2. Please use the code below:

```r
library(maps)

Sampling_coord <- read.csv() # Localisation of the file with all the coordinates

palette(c("yellow","green","red")) # Project only islands
png(, res=300, width = 15, height = 15, units = "cm") # Create a file in output

map(xlim =c(-10,0), ylim=c(55,60), fill=F, col="black",mar=c(1,1,1,1)) # coordinates of the area

islands=subset(Sampling_coord, Project == 'Island') # Substract only the island samples

points(islands$Long,islands$Lat,col=islands$SiteMiteBees,pch=19) # Put the points on the map and color by type of site

# Put the labels on the sites
text(islands$Long, islands$Lat,label=islands$Code, cex=0.8, adj=1.4)
legend("bottomright",legend=unique(islands$SiteMiteBees),pch=19,col=unique(islands$SiteMiteBees),cex=0.6)
dev.off()
```

## 3. Please find the sites below:

```
58.223914;-6.386988;L;Island;Varroa;Honey Bees;Island + Varroa + Honey Bees

57.051801;-5.923568;S;Island;Varroa;Honey Bees;Island + Varroa + Honey Bees

56.598782;-6.627109;Coll;Island;Varroa;Honey Bees;Island + Varroa + Honey Bees

56.62349;-6.073362;Mull;Island;NoVarroa;Honey Bees;Island + Honey Bees

55.698677;-6.445954;I;Island;NoVarroa;Honey Bees;Island + Honey Bees

56.959589;-7.443962;B;Island;NoVarroa;Honey Bees;Island + Honey Bees

56.068724;-6.196989;C;Island;NoVarroa;Honey Bees;Island + Honey Bees

57.153458;-7.308724;SU;Island;NoVarroa;No Honey Bees;Island 

57.084832;-7.310713;E;Island;NoVarroa;No Honey Bees;Island

57.010631;-6.265324;R;Island;NoVarroa;No Honey Bees;Island
```

Comment: What's your objective ? Do you meet a problem ? If you want to produce maps, you should have look at `sf` (spatial data analysis), `cartography` or `tmap` (to produce maps) features. Without a better description of your motivation, it is hard to help you

Comment: Are we in the Seychelles?